# Drawing transparent image doesn't work

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, transparent

I have a PictureBox Control that's background color is set to transparent. I'd like to draw an image on this control (Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display#/media/File:7-segment.svg) but instead of the transparent background it's background color is white (unfortunately paint doesn't support alpha channel).

Here's how I try to draw the bitmap:

```
private void DrawPictureBox() 
{
    pbScreen.Image = Update();
}

private Bitmap CreateBackgroundBitmap()
{
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("empty");
    bitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.White);

    return bitmap;
}

private ImageAttributes GetImageAttributes()
{
    float[][] matrixItems = {
        new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        new float[] {0, 0, 0, Contrast, 0},
        new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};

    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(matrixItems);

    ImageAttributes imageAtt = new ImageAttributes();
    imageAtt.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);

    return imageAtt;
}

private void DrawSegment(ref Graphics g, Digit digit, int Position = 0)
{
    if (digit == null)
        return;

    Bitmap buffer = digit.CreateBitmapFromFile(digit.CreateFileNameFromContent());
    buffer.MakeTransparent(Color.White);

    g.DrawImage(buffer, new Rectangle(0 + Position * 43, 0, 43, 67), 0.0f, 0.0f, 43, 67, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, this.GetImageAttributes());

}

public Bitmap Update()
{
    Bitmap buffer = CreateBackgroundBitmap();

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(buffer);

    g.DrawImage(buffer, new Rectangle(0, 0, 301, 67), 0.0f, 0.0f, 301, 67, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, this.GetImageAttributes());

    if (State == Powerstate.on)
    {
        // Draw segments
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.Count(); i++)
        {
            DrawSegment(ref g, digits[i], i);

            if (digits[i]?.Dot == Dot.dot_on)
            {
                DrawPoint(ref g, digits[i], i);
            }
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Drawing the Segments (drawing points is similar) works as expected but drawing the background won't accept the transparency that is beeing created by 'GetImageAttributes()'.

Another strange thing is, that if I add

```
g.Clear(color: Color.Black);
```

before

```
g.DrawImage(buffer, new Rectangle(0, 0, 301, 67), 0.0f, 0.0f, 301, 67, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, this.GetImageAttributes());
```

in the Update() method my Grapics 'g' is simply black - no matter if I keep or remove

```
bitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
```

in 'CreateBackgroundBitmap()', but drawing the segments over the black background works as expected?!

Does someone see where the problem is? What do I miss?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it. I suppose I didn't understand how an Graphics object interacts with the bitmap, that the graphics object was made of.

Here's how it had to be changed:

```
public Bitmap Update()
{
    Bitmap background = new Bitmap(301, 67);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(background);

    g.Clear(color: Color.White);

    Bitmap buffer = CreateBackgroundBitmap();

    g.DrawImage(buffer, new Rectangle(0, 0, 301, 67), 0.0f, 0.0f, 301, 67, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, this.GetImageAttributes());

    if (State == Powerstate.on)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.Count(); i++)
        {
            DrawSegment(ref g, digits[i], i);

            if (digits[i]?.Dot == Dot.dot_on)
            {
                DrawPoint(ref g, digits[i], i);
            }
        }
    }

    return background;
}
```